# List unattached document elements

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension, getelementsbytagname

I'm trying to create an extension for Chrome to control playback using global hotkeys. I've faced such problem: somewhere the `<audio/>` elements are not attached to DOM. These elements are audible, but I can't get them with `document.querySelector('audio')` (because it iterates over attached DOM elements only).

Using DevTools I can see these elements:

```
> queryObjects(HTMLAudioElement)
< undefined
  (3) [audio, audio, audio]
```

But it's impossible to use this function outside DevTools (it doesn't even return result - this func just prints result to the console).

I'm looking a way to get unattached audio elements from the content_script (or background) of my extension.

I've tried:

1. `document.getElementsByTagName('audio')`
2. `document.querySelectorAll('audio')`
3. `document.evaluate('//audio', ...`
4. `document.createNodeIterator(document.body, NodeFilter.SHOW_ALL, ...`
5. redefine constructor of `HTMLAudioElement` and `document.createElement` (failed: extension has its own `window` and linked `document`)
6. listen `'play'` and `'pause'` events - they don't bubble

Have any other ideas? Maybe there are some extension-specific capabilities?

Comment: re 5: due to the world isolation you need to [Insert code into the page context using a content script](//stackoverflow.com/q/9515704)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @wOxxOm

I've followed my idea #5: redefine constructor of <s>`HTMLAudioElement`</s> `Audio` and `document.createElement`

#### inject.js:

```
var instances = [];

document.createElement = (function () {
    var _createElement = document.createElement;
    return function createElement() {
        var result = _createElement.apply(document, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0));
        if (result.tagName === 'AUDIO') {
            instances.push(result);
        }
        return result;
    };
})();

window.Audio = (function () {
    var _Audio = window.Audio;
    function Audio() {
        var result = new _Audio();
        instances.push(result);
        return result;
    };
    Audio.prototype = Object.create(_Audio);
    Audio.prototype.constructor = Audio;
    return Audio;
})();

// further code (dom-event-based communication, misc functions etc)...
```

#### content.js:

```
var injected = document.createElement('script');
injected.src = chrome.extension.getURL('inject.js');
(document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(injected);
```

#### manifest.json:

```
{
      "manifest_version": 2
    , "content_scripts": [{
          "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
        , "js": ["content.js"]
        , "run_at": "document_start" // <-- important
        , "all_frames": true
    }]
    , "web_accessible_resources": [
        "inject.js"
    ]

    // ...
}
```

It's harmful to store all instances in an array, but this is the only way that I see: `WeakSet` is non-iterable.